# evaluate $\lim_{z\to 0} (\frac{\overline{z}}{z}-\frac{z}{\overline{z}})$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers

> find the limit (if there it exists)
>
> $$\lim_{z\to 0} \left(\frac{\overline{z}}{z}-\frac{z}{\overline{z}}\right)$$

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \left(\frac{\overline{z}}{z}-\frac{z}{\overline{z}}\right)=\lim_{x,y\to (0,0)} \left(\frac{x-yi}{x+yi}-\frac{x+yi}{x-yi}\right)=\lim_{x,y\to (0,0)} \frac{-4xyi}{x^2+y^2}$$

let $x=x\text{ , }y=mx$

$$\lim_{(x,mx)\to (0,0)} \frac{-4mx^2i}{x^2(m+1)}=\lim_{(x,mx)\to (0,0)} \frac{-4mi}{m+1}$$

Can we say that because the function depends on $m$ there is no limit? [according to Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bz%5Cto%200%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bz*%7D%7Bz%7D-%5Cfrac%7Bz%7D%7Bz*%7D) the limit is $0$

(How do there derive $\overline{z}$? shouldn't it be not differentiable at any point?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument from $m$-dependence is right; there is no limit. Another method writes $z=re^{i\theta}$ so you can show the expression whose $r\to 0$ limit is sought is $\theta $-dependent, so no limit exists. Perhaps you should report the error to Wolfram.

Comment: Using $z=re^{i\theta}$ I get $e^{-2i\theta}-e^{2i\theta}$ which is as you said \theta dependent

Comment: Not worth reporting. Mathematica cannot and never has been able to evaluate limits of this kind. There are good links about this on either MathOverflow or MSE, I can't recall